# Is there any way to use dynamic upstream in Nginx for both HTTP and TCP

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

We are looking for an option to configure upstream servers dynamically with Restapi or any other available option without stopping nginx server.

Answer (score 0):

the solution i can offer is with nginx perl module which by default it is not compiled along with nginx ( you should install nginx perl module seperately ). you can write perl code to request backends through rest api and return it to nginx [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_perl_module.html) you can find more info.